# Put an array into a hash of hashes, transforming it into a Hash itself

Tags: perl

```
my %hash = @array;
```

transforms an array into a hash, but how can do the same with **$hash{something}**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$hash{something} = { @array };
```

The `{}` around it creates a hashref.

Comment: Or `%{ $hash{something} } = @array`

Comment: No, putting the {} around it creates an anonymous hash which contents are extracted from the array.  He may want this instead: `$hash{something} = [ @array ];` This creates an anonymous array and store a reference to it in the hash keyed by 'something'.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I looked for. Sorry for the short description, I have been in a hurry.

Answer (score 5):

When you write:

```
my %hash = @array;
```

What Perl sees is:

```
my %hash = ($array[0], $array[1], ... $array[$#array]);
```

So the `@array` is expanded into a list, and that list is assigned to the plural `%hash`.  The list must have an even number of elements, or you will get a warning (assuming you are using `use warnings;` in your script, which you always should.  `use strict;` as well).

Broken down even more, it is:

```
my %hash;
$hash{$array[0]} = $array[1];
$hash{$array[2]} = $array[3];
...
$hash{$array[$#array - 1]} = $array[$#array];
```

So with the translation from `@array` to `%hash` explained, to insert this hash into a hash of hashes at a particular key:

```
$HoH{key} = \%hash;
```

Where the `\` character takes a reference to `%hash`.  If `%hash` is not needed elsewhere you could constrain it with a block:

```
{
    my %hash = @array;
    $HoH{key} = \%hash;
}
```

Using a `do {...}` makes it a little shorter:

```
$HoH{key} = do {my %hash = @array; \%hash};
```

But not much shorter.  If the above seems tedious to you, it should.  In Perl, the above construct can be reduced to:

```
$HoH{key} = { @array };
```

Where the `{...}` denotes the anonymous hash reference constructor, equivalent to

```
do {my %hash = (...); \%hash}
```

In addition to `{...}`, Perl provides the `[...]` construct to create anonymous array references.  The `...` of both constructs sees list context.